# How to include library's local dependencies to aar

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, aar

I'm building a module which depends on other modules. So far all modules have been used within the same project, but now I need to ship one of the modules as a standalone. For example I have modules `Core`, `Util`, `Feature` and `App`. Until now, `Feature` was using `Core` and `Util` with `implementation project(':core')` and `implementation project(':util')`. Same goes for `App`. Now when I built the `aar` for `Feature`, I noticed that other modules' code is absent from the `aar`. If I try to publish it, `maven-publish` tries to generate a `pom` with the local dependencies. Can I generate an `aar` for `Feature`, that includes both `Core` and `Util` in its binary, instead of having to publish the other modules first and adding them to the `pom`?

**Update**: it seems that what I try to achieve is not straight-forward possible and apparently there is an [issue on google tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62121508#comment149) for this and Google is "actively working" on it. In the meantime I have to find a workaround.